# How to set Alternate Row Color in a Gridview Android?

Tags: android, gridview

How to set alternate row color in a gridview? I have searched a lot of tutorial about how to set grid view row colors,but nothing about gridview row color. I got list view with alternate row color only.  I need alternate row should be white and black. Here I Include my codes. Please help me!!!!!!!!!!

**Here is Java Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
            "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    }
```

**Here is xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</GridView>
```

Please provide good tutorial or sample Example.  Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom adapter and override its `getView` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,
            R.layout.item, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    String[] objects;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, android.view.View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            tv = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        tv.setText(objects[position]);
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        else
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        return tv;
    }
}
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

Comment: Mohsen Afshin@ It works fine Sir. Thanks for your Answer. One more thing is how to change the alternate Column color?

Comment: It's the same as rows, but you should manually set the Row and Column of the cells (inside getView) and then based on the column number change the back color. It's on you to have a logic to determine row and column number of each cell (character, here)

Comment: Mohsen Afshin@ Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom Adaptor and in Custom adaptor
you will be having method **getView**

Use this code in your getView Method

```
if(position % ( 2*columnCount ) == 0)
{
// set first color 
}
else 
{
 // set alternate row's  color
}
```

Comment: It would be more like `position % columnCount`.

Comment: @kcoppock ya but not exactly like that it should be like this

Comment: Hi-Tech KitKat Android@ Thanks for your Answer Sir.