# Changing custom gridview bg color

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view

How can i change the background color of a custom gridview dynamically?
I have a gridview and a class which includes the state of the devices. So if a device is active its color should be green in gridview.

I can get the state of each device but not sure how to or where to implement this background change.. I tried to change in my CustomGridView class but it didnt work correctly. I will be appreciate if you guys show me or tell me a way to do it correctly

```
ArrayList<IpPhone> data = new ArrayList<IpPhone>();

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<IpPhone> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null; 
    ViewGroup vg = parent;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_phoneNumber);
        holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_ipAddress);
        holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_phoneState);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else {

        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //I tried this if else to change bg colors but it didnt work

    if(data.get(position).state == "0")
    {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if (data.get(position).state == "1"){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    IpPhone item = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle1.setText(item.getphoneNumber());
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(item.getipAddress());
    holder.txtTitle3.setText(item.getphoneLocation());
    return row;

}
```

[image: The Output]

Comment: a little googling, Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961709/how-to-set-alternate-row-color-in-a-gridview-android) out

Comment: there is nothing different in the link you suggested sir. I ve already done this in my code..

Comment: just a thought, since the adapter reuse rows, put this before you test  what color to put. row.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT); This way you are resetting the row before changing it. Maybe you don't need it, depends on if the state == "X" can be more then 1 or 2

Comment: thank you sir :) i changed state == "X" to state.equals("X") and it works..

Comment: yes of course `equals` for string compare. I did not see that, good work